# Adobe premiere pro video overexposed after import

Tags: premiere, gamma

I'm importing Samsung Galaxy Note 10 plus recorded videos with following codec information to the premiere pro CC v13 (windows) and the imported video looks over-exposed with incorrect gamma.

> Codec: MPEG-H Part2/HEVC (H.265) (hvc1),
>   Video resolution: 1920x1080,
>   Buffer dimensions: 1920x1088,
>   Frame rate: 29.993225,
>   Color primaries: ITU-R BT.2020,
>   Color transfer function: SMPTE ST2084,
>   Color space: ITU-R BT.2020 Range,
>   Max. luminance: 1000.0000 cd/m²,
>   Min. luminance: 0.0050 cd/m²,
>   Primary R: x=0.1500 y=0.0600,
>   Primary G: x=0.6800 y=0.3200,
>   Primary B: x=0.2650 y=0.6900,
>   White point: x=0.3127 y=0.3290

Video looks normally when playing on VLC media player or on the phone. I have installed kLite Mega codec pack 14.4.5 on my computer. Video become somewhat normal when exposure is reduced in between (-2)-(-3).

If you have any clue on this or a solution appreciates a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened due to the display's inability to handle HDR videos. Color space: ITU-R BT.2020 defines a HDR video. As a solution I used 'confirm SDR' effect in premiere pro which converts the video into HDR color range.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from the exact same problem. What you can do (what is a tedious process) is to convert all your hdr files to sdr files as shown in this video with vlc:

Comment: Welcome! Link only answers are discouraged in case the contents are no longer available in the future. Can you summarize the contents of the video?